# $X$ is a Banach space, $T \in B(X)$ and $T^*$ be its adjoint, show that $ \lVert Tx \rVert \geq \lVert (T^*)^{-1}\rVert^{-1}\lVert x \rVert$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

> Let X be a complex Banach space. Let $T\in B(X)$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$. Let $T^*\in B(X^*)$ be the adjoint of $T$.
>
> Prove: If $T^*$ is invertible, then for all elements $x\in X$,
> $$ \|Tx \| \geq \| (T^*)^{-1}\|^{-1}\| x \|$$
> and use the inequality to prove that $T$ is invertible

Comment: $$(T^*)^{-1}=(T^{-1})^*,\quad \|(T^{-1})^*\|=\|T^{-1}\|$$

Comment: @Vim that's not an axiom, it must be proven

Comment: @Omnomnomnom please refer to page 36 [here](http://www.math.ust.hk/~makyli/4063/fanotes2_140513.pdf).

Comment: @Vim I want to use $\lVert Tx \rVert \geq \lVert (T^*)^{-1}\rVert^{-1} \lVert x \rVert $ to prove $T$ is invertible. But by writing $T^{-1}$, you have already assumed $T$ is invertible?

Comment: @SHBaoS in case of Banach spaces, the invertibility of the adjoint is equivalent to that of the original operator. Please also refer to the page I gave to Omnom. (I actually didn't know you want to use the inequality to prove invertibility)

Comment: @SHBaos in other words, it suffices to note that
$$I = [T^*(T^*)^{-1}]^* = [(T^*)^{-1}]^* T^{**} = [(T^*)^{-1}]^* T$$
and similarly for the opposite multiplication, which tells us that $T$ is invertible.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How to derive the equations you give?

Comment: @SHBaoS the one ingredient missing is that for operators $A,B$, we have $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$.  This is straightforward to prove from the definition of the adjoint.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We have $I=[(T^*)^{-1}]^* T$ and then $1= \lVert [(T^*)^{-1}]^* T\rVert$ and I still can't get $\lVert T \rVert = \lVert (T^*)^{-1} \rVert^{-1}$

Comment: Note that
$$\|x\| = \|[(T^*)^{-1}]^*Tx\| \leq \|[(T^*)^{-1}]^*\| \; \|Tx\|$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $[(T^*)^{-1}]^* \in B(X^{**})$ but $Tx \in X$. Also, $\lVert [(T^*)^{-1}]^*\rVert $ is not $\lVert (T^*)^{-1}\rVert$, right?

Comment: @SHBaoS right! We're in a Banach space, not a Hilbert space.  I'm being dumb.  So, I'm not sure now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54573/discussion-between-shbaos-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: @SHBaoS actually $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$ always holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. By Hahn-Banach there is $f\in X^\ast$ with $\|f\|=1$ and
$|f(x)|=\|x\|$. Then we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\|x\|&=|f(x)| \\
&=|(T^\ast)^{-1}(T^\ast(f))(x)|\\
&\le \|(T^\ast)^{-1}\||(T^\ast(f))(x)|\\
&=\|(T^\ast)^{-1}\||(f\circ T)(x)|\\
&\le\|(T^\ast)^{-1}\|\|T(x)\|,
\end{align} $$
which is equivalent to the inequality of the statement. This immediately implies that $T$ is injective and that if $(Tx_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, also $(x_n)$ must be Cauchy. Thus, $T(X)$ is complete.

It remains to be shown that $T(X)=X$. Suppose this is not the case. Then choose $x\in X\setminus T(X)$. Again by Hahn-Banach and the fact that $T(X)$ is closed, there is a functional $f\in X^\ast$ such that $f$ is zero on $T(X)$, but $f(x)\neq 0$. This is a contradiction, since $T^\ast$ is injective, but $T^\ast(f) = f\circ T = 0$.

Comment: Why we want to show T(X) is complete? Isn't bijectivity  enough?

Comment: @Kenneth.K To apply Hahn-Banach at the end, it is necessary that $T(X)$ is closed. This follows from the fact that $T(X)$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we have, 
\begin{split}
\|x\| &=& \sup\{|\langle x,y\rangle| ; \|y\|=1\}\\
&=& \sup\{|\langle T^{-1}Tx,y\rangle| ; \|y\|=1\}\\
&=& \sup\{|\langle T^{-1}Tx,(T^{-1})^*y\rangle| ; \|y\|=1\}\\
&\le& \|Tx\|\sup\{\|T^{-1})^*y\| ; \|y\|=1\}\\
& = &\|Tx\|\|(T^{-1})^*\|
\end{split}
that is $$\|x\| |(T^{-1})^*\|^{-1}\le \|Tx\|$$